# Why there's a update state delay in checkbox, React

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

Something very weird is going on with my code and it does not makes any sense. Every time I save/store some data it has a "delay" like for example if I click 2 checkboxes, when I click the first one nothing happens, when I click the second one it grabs the value of the first one I clicked. let me show you:

[image]

Now the same happens when I click the one that selects all of them but it does not affects the maths at least (which is the most important part) here:

[image]

if I unselect all it shows that all the values where being saved at least:

[image]

now comes the even more weird part if I do one by one then the maths doesn't match and is because is not "adding" the one I click first:

[image]

Here is my piece of code I mean technically is working but clearly I'm missing something idk let me know if you require something else:

```
// "librosnuevos" get updated on the firebase I will not add it cause I think is not necessary 

const [librosNuevos, setLibrosNuevos] = useState([]);
const [LibrosID, setLibrosID] = useState([]);
    const handleChange = (e, data) => {
    const { name, checked } = e.target;
    if (checked) {
      // if cheked and selectall checkbox add all fileds to selectedList
      if (name === "allSelect") {

        setLibrosID(librosNuevos);
        let x = 0
        librosNuevos.map((i) => {
          x += i.precio
          setTPLibrosNuevos(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2))
        })

      } else {
        // if cheked and specific checkbox add specific field to selectedList
        setLibrosID([...LibrosID, data]);

        let x = 0
        LibrosID.map((i) => {
          x += i.precio
          setTPLibrosNuevos(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2))
        })
      }
    } else {
      // if uncheked and selectall checkbox add remove all fileds from selectedList
      if (name === "allSelect") {
        setLibrosID([]);

        let x = 0
        librosNuevos.map((i) => {
          x = 0
          setTPLibrosNuevos(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2))
        })

      } else {
        // if uncheked and specific checkbox remove specific field from selectedList
        let tempuser = LibrosID.filter((item) => item.id !== data.id);
        setLibrosID(tempuser);

        let x = 0
        tempuser.map((i) => {
          x += i.precio
          setTPLibrosNuevos(parseFloat(x).toFixed(2))
        })
      }
    }
    console.log(LibrosID)
  };

//Parent Checkbox
<input
type="checkbox"
className="form-check-input"
name="allSelect"
checked={LibrosID?.length === librosNuevos?.length}
onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, librosNuevos)}
/>

//Mapped checkbox-child

{librosNuevos.map((libros, index) => (
<tr key={libros.id || index}>
<td >
<input
type="checkbox"
className="form-check-input"
 name={libros.id}
checked={LibrosID.some((item) => item?.id === libros.id)}
onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, libros)}
/>

... some smart code that finish the table
}
```

Gifs requested:

[image: Gif 1]
[image: Gif 2]

This is what I get after trying that answer:

[image]

is half working now which is still an upgrade, still need to make the prices add up correctly this is what I tried:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log(LibrosID);
 }, [LibrosID])

 useEffect(() => {
  console.log(tpLibrosNuevos);
}, [tpLibrosNuevos])
```

tpLibrosNuevos is the total price that it should update every time I select an option but it only does it after the first one. Maybe my maths are wrong somewhere? I doubled checked and doesn't seem to be the case...

Comment: A gif would be better to visualize the issue.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, I'll upload one in a moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not necessarily a delay.
`setState` is an async function, meaning that, since you log to console right after setting the state, you can't be sure that it has finished.

You can check your state using a `useEffect` that has `state` as a dependency.

Like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(LibrosID, librosNuevos);
}, [LibrosID, librosNuevos])
```

This is a callback that will, by definition, run only after the `LibrosID` or `librosNuevos` have been changed.

You can read more about this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the useEffect() will run if _either_ of the two, `LibrosID` OR `librosNuevos` have been changed. Not and AND condition.

Comment: You're right, I worded this incorrectly. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: That indeed fixed the "delay" when I select the checkbox, but the maths are still "delay" I tried: `useEffect(() => { }, [LibrosID, tpLibrosNuevos])`  because those 2 are the variables that always are changing. Librosnuevos is an array that comes from somewhere else and already has data is never changing. Anyways the maths are still "delay" any tips ? tpLibrosnuevos stand for TotalPriceLibrosNuevos btw.

Comment: I tried by doing them separately and still didn't work idk what else to do now

Comment: I see. Are you still having issues with this?
P.S. would recommend not to do `setTPLibrosNuevos` inside the map functions, and to set it after instead so that it will happen only once, and not for every item. SetState is a "heavy" function that produces re-renders of the component. It quickly becomes a performance issue in large-scale applications.