# How to make data persist on refresh React JS?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, local-storage, refresh

I have a code where I mount a table with some firebase data but for some reason the values disappear and I been struggling for the next 2 weeks trying to solve this issue I haven't found a solution to this and I have asked twice already and I have try everything so far but it keeps disappearing.

**Important Update**
I just want to clarify the following apparently I was wrong the issue wasn't because it was a nested collection as someone mentioned in another question. The issue is because my "user" is getting lost in the process when I refresh.

I bring the user from the login to the app like this:

`<Estudiantes user={user} />`

and then I receive it as a props
`function ListadoPedidos({user})`

but is getting lost and because is getting lost when I try to use my firebase as:

`estudiantesRef = db.collection("usuarios").doc(user.uid).collection("estudiantes")`

since the user is "lost" then the uid will be null. Since is null it will never reach the collection and the docs.

Comment: not sure, but it probably has to do with the setItem in the useEffect without the dependency array. It's being run on every render, so maybe it's setting the value to [].

Comment: Really? I have a similar code somewhere else and it doesn't disappear in refresh. let me try adding it.

Comment: That does in fact fix the problem however, that makes a new problem since is a use effect is getting looped infinitely ... @nullptr and now I have another question why does it requires that while when is 1 collection of search it doesn't require it ?

Comment: This is exactly what happens now: 1. I refresh 2.The data disappears 3. the data comes back and is looping endlessly.

Comment: What does looping endless mean? What's happening?

Comment: @DemiPixel is doing the process endlessly, is calling the data over and over and over and over. Maybe a Gif/Picture will help one sec.

Comment: What is console.log'ing that? Is that the console.log inside the "onSnapshot"? If so, that seems like an issue with `onSnapshot` calling console.log over and over again?

Comment: yes is inside the snapshot, however the snapshot function is coded correctly. I used the exact same code in another "path" and it does bring the whole table and it does not disappear on refresh however it does only 1 collection search and not 2 like on the one I just posted. Do you have a suggestion to "better up" my current snapshot ? is not like there are multiple ways to code the calling of data from firebase.

Comment: update the code in the question, please.

Comment: Done. All I added was the dependency

Comment: I still don't see a dependency array in useEffect

Comment: isn't array dependency the last bit you add in the useEffect() ? "}, [estudiantes]);" I honestly do not know I'm new to react.

Comment: Okay, i see. You added the array to the wrong useEffect. Now you're updating the variable inside the useEffect, but since the variable changed, the useEffect runs again, causing an infinite loop. I'll add an answer with what I think the problem is

Answer (score 2):

I have a simple solution for you. Simply raise the parsing of localStorage up one level, passing the preloadedState into your component as a prop, and then using that to initialize your state variable.

```js
const ListadoEstudiantes = (props) => {
  const estData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('estudiantes'));
  return <Listado preloadedState={estData} {...props} />;
};
```

Then initialize state with the prop

```js
  const initialState = props.preloadedState || [];
  const [estudiantesData, setEstudiantesData] = useState(initialState);
```

And finally, update the useEffect hook to persist state any time it changes.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('estudiantes', JSON.stringify(estudiantes));
  }, [estudiantes]);
```

### Full Code

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { db } from './firebase';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import './ListadoEstudiantes.css';
import {
  DataGrid,
  GridToolbarContainer,
  GridToolbarFilterButton,
  GridToolbarDensitySelector,
} from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { Button, Container } from '@material-ui/core';
import { IconButton } from '@mui/material';
import PersonAddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PersonAddSharp';
import ShoppingCartSharpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCartSharp';
import DeleteOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeleteOutlined';
import { Box } from '@mui/system';

const ListadoEstudiantes = (props) => {
  const estData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('estudiantes'));
  return <Listado preloadedState={estData} {...props} />;
};

const Listado = ({ user, preloadedState }) => {
  const history = useHistory('');
  const crearEstudiante = () => {
    history.push('/Crear_Estudiante');
  };

  const initialState = preloadedState || [];
  const [estudiantesData, setEstudiantesData] = useState(initialState);

  const parseData = {
    pathname: '/Crear_Pedidos',
    data: estudiantesData,
  };

  const realizarPedidos = () => {
    if (estudiantesData == 0) {
      window.alert('Seleccione al menos un estudiante');
    } else {
      history.push(parseData);
    }
  };

  function CustomToolbar() {
    return (
      <GridToolbarContainer>
        <GridToolbarFilterButton />
        <GridToolbarDensitySelector />
      </GridToolbarContainer>
    );
  }

  const [estudiantes, setEstudiantes] = useState([]);
  const [selectionModel, setSelectionModel] = useState([]);
  const columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 100 },

    { field: 'nombre', headerName: 'Nombre', width: 200 },

    { field: 'colegio', headerName: 'Colegio', width: 250 },

    { field: 'grado', headerName: 'Grado', width: 150 },
    {
      field: 'delete',
      width: 75,
      sortable: false,
      disableColumnMenu: true,
      renderHeader: () => {
        return (
          <IconButton
            onClick={() => {
              const selectedIDs = new Set(selectionModel);
              estudiantes
                .filter((x) => selectedIDs.has(x.id))
                .map((x) => {
                  db.collection('usuarios')
                    .doc(user.uid)
                    .collection('estudiantes')
                    .doc(x.uid)
                    .delete();
                });
            }}
          >
            <DeleteOutlinedIcon />
          </IconButton>
        );
      },
    },
  ];

  const deleteProduct = (estudiante) => {
    if (window.confirm('Quiere borrar este estudiante ?')) {
      db.collection('usuarios').doc(user.uid).collection('estudiantes').doc(estudiante).delete();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {}, [estudiantesData]);

  const estudiantesRef = db.collection('usuarios').doc(user.uid).collection('estudiantes');
  useEffect(() => {
    estudiantesRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const tempData = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        tempData.push(data);
      });
      setEstudiantes(tempData);
      console.log(estudiantes);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('estudiantes', JSON.stringify(estudiantes));
  }, [estudiantes]);

  return (
    <Container fixed>
      <Box mb={5} pt={2} sx={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
        <Button
          startIcon={<PersonAddIcon />}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          size="medium"
          onClick={crearEstudiante}
        >
          Crear Estudiantes
        </Button>
        <Box pl={25} pt={2} mb={2} sx={{ height: '390px', width: '850px', textAlign: 'center' }}>
          <DataGrid
            rows={estudiantes}
            columns={columns}
            pageSize={5}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
            components={{
              Toolbar: CustomToolbar,
            }}
            checkboxSelection
            //Store Data from the row in another variable
            onSelectionModelChange={(id) => {
              setSelectionModel(id);
              const selectedIDs = new Set(id);
              const selectedRowData = estudiantes.filter((row) => selectedIDs.has(row.id));
              setEstudiantesData(selectedRowData);
            }}
            {...estudiantes}
          />
        </Box>
        <Button
          startIcon={<ShoppingCartSharpIcon />}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          size="medium"
          onClick={realizarPedidos}
        >
          Crear pedido
        </Button>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: Question how do I get use of my user variable though? I wouldn't be able to get the `user.uid` from firebase

Comment: @ReactPotato I have updated my code example with destructuring the user and preloadedState props. Notice that ListadoEstudiantes props are spread onto Listado. So you can simply pass a user prop to ListadoEstudiantes as expected.

Comment: This works like the answer from @nullptr only issue is that is now endlessly rendering. Edit: if I remove the [estudiantes] from the useeffect under the firebase set up it works fine! just update your answer :3

Comment: There just seem to be 1 issue though when I try to delete something it just come backs when I refresh

Comment: @ReactPotato okay, I have updated the code! I only addressed your question, and did not address other issues in your code. But I can take a closer look at refactoring your code if you would like?

Comment: Actually I was wrong I now know why it wasn't deleting is because leaving [estudiantes] dependency in the useEffect for firebase also generates an infinite loop

Comment: I'll attack an image

Comment: I have attack an image and also update the code, idk why I get endless loops I don't understand.

Comment: @ReactPotato why do you have separate useState vars for `estudiantesData`, and `estudiantes`?

Comment: 2 different values. When I select something and I console log it it shows nothing and then I select something else and it shows the first one I select is basically to fix a visual bug no biggies -> [update state delay in checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69330439/why-theres-a-update-state-delay-in-checkbox-react)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it's because this `useEffect` does not have a dependency array and is bring run on every render.

```
useEffect (() => {
   window.localStorage.setItem("estudiantes", JSON.stringify(estudiantes))
 })
```

Try adding a dependency array as follows:

```
useEffect (() => {
if (estudiantes && estudiantes.length>0)
   window.localStorage.setItem("estudiantes", JSON.stringify(estudiantes))
 },[estudiantes])
```

This will still set the `localStorage` to `[]` when it runs on the first render. But when the data is fetched and `estudiantes` is set, the `localStorage` value will be updated. So I've added a check to check if it's not the empty array.

Change the dependency array of this `useEffect` to `[]`:

```
  estudiantesRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    const tempData = [];
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data();
      tempData.push(data);
    });
    setEstudiantes(tempData);
    console.log(estudiantes)
  })
 }, []);
```

Comment: Now the data disappears after refresh, but the loop is gone (because I removed the array dependency of the snapshot). BTW it was doing the same behaviour before the localStorage I added the localStorage because people said that would fixed but it didn't

Comment: Will checking if the value is [] before updating the localstorage solve your issue?

Comment: I've updated the anwer @ReactPotato

Comment: That didn't work neither sorry, data is still disappearing after refresh.

Comment: Can we have a discussion in chat? The link to the chat will be in the comments to the question

Comment: Sure I have no problem with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237942/discussion-between-nullptr-and-reactpotato).

Comment: @ReactPotato here's the link https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237942/discussion-between-nullptr-and-reactpotato

Comment: Let me know if wanna chat again to see other possibilities, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- The data flow in your code is somewhat contradictory, so I modify your code, and it works fine.
- You can also try delete or add button, it will modify firebase collection, then update local data.
- You can click refresh button in `codesandbox previewer` (not browser) to observe the status of data update.

#### Here is the code fargment :

```js
  // Set value of `localStorage` to component state if it exist.
  useEffect(() => {
    const localStorageEstData = window.localStorage.getItem("estudiantes");
    localStorageEstData && setEstudiantes(JSON.parse(localStorageEstData));
  }, []);

  // Sync remote data from firebase to local component data state.
  useEffect(() => {
    // Subscribe onSnapshot
    const unSubscribe = onSnapshot(
      collection(db, "usuarios", user.id, "estudiantes"),
      (snapshot) => {
        const remoteDataSource = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data()
        }));
        console.info(remoteDataSource);
        setEstudiantes(remoteDataSource);
      }
    );
    return () => {
      //unSubscribe when component unmount.
      unSubscribe();
    };
  }, [user.id]);

  // when `estudiantes` state update, `localStorage` will update too.
  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("estudiantes", JSON.stringify(estudiantes));
  }, [estudiantes]);
```

#### Here is the full code sample :

[image: Edit TextField selectionStart]

**Hope to help you :)**

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna try this I'm just trying to set up the firebase part (which would be your simulated data)

Comment: it didn't work with firebase :c

Comment: @ReactPotato I update answer with firebase, please check and hope to help you.
(you can try add, delete, refresh.)

Comment: for some reason it says: Attempted import error: 'collection' is not exported from 'firebase/firestore'. Quick question how can I modify it so it goes through more than one collection? Because this issue only happens because I'm going through 2 collections. That code will only go through the first collection which is `user` but not to `estudiantes` with is the second collection am I wrong?

Comment: What I'm trying to get is a Collection inside a Collection, will post image for better understanding.

Comment: 1. `Attempted import error: 'collection' is not exported from 'firebase/firestore'. ` cause our firebase package version are different, I use the v9.1.2, but it doesn’t matter, you just change to your version usage.      2. Okay....  I will make a `Collection inside a Collection `  sample after I get off work.
@ReactPotato

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, I modified it to multiple collections. Actually there is not much difference, but I still hope it helps. @ReactPotato

Comment: Thank you very much, sadly I found out I was in the wrong and got misinformed. it wasn't because it was a nested collection it was because my user is getting lost in the process. I really appreciate all the help and I can't believe I got stuck so long in something as trivial as this ugh... thank you again.

Comment: Never mind, life is sometimes full of surprises. I'm glad you solved the problem. Congratulations!  :) 
@ReactPotato

Comment: sorry for wasting your time. But now I don't understand how to save the prop user in the localStorage beause when I refresh it sets to null which means localStorage goes back to null as well, I hate this

Comment: This may be a new question. I suggest you open a new post to ask, but I can give a very rough solution here: When you get the value of `user` and save it in `localStorage` at the same time, so it is less likely to cause conflicts.
@ReactPotato

Comment: Yeah I was thinking on making a new one because I'm getting the value properly but when I store it it says [object, object] thanks for everything again and sorry for the time lost.

Comment: I fixed all I had to do was to add user as array dependency jesus christ.